# bash script and command definition

Tags: bash

Got a little bash script like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
TIME_CMD='/usr/bin/time -f "%E execution time"'

${TIME_CMD} ls
```

Only problem: doesn't work:

```
/usr/bin/time: cannot run execution: No such file or directory
Command exited with non-zero status 127
"0:00.00
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The command works when run directly, i.e. not through setting a variable and then executing it. The problem lies somewhere in that in attempts to execute the bits in the format string, but I wouldn't know why. Perhaps ask on superuser?

Comment: I think bash is `fork`-ing a process with `argv[] = { "/usr/bin/time", "-f", "\"%E", "execution", "time\"" }`. But I don't know the syntax to correct the escaping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try making it...

```
#!/bin/bash
TIME_CMD='/usr/bin/time -f "%E execution time"'

eval "$TIME_CMD ls"
```

This will utilize bash to re-parse the command string after it has been constructed, so that the quoted argument will be recognized properly.

Comment: That's a heavy-duty way of executing it compared with simply using `eval $TIME_CMD ls`.

Comment: @Jonathan - Good point. Too used to writing things that are invoking `bash -c` from Python as opposed to already being in bash. :)

Answer (score 5):

Storing commands in variables is generally a bad idea (see [BashFAQ #050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for details).  The reason it's not working as you expect is that quoting inside variable values is ignored (unless you run it through something like `eval`, which then tends to lead to other parsing oddities).

In your case, I see three fairly straightforward ways to do it.  First, you can use an alias instead of a variable:

```
alias TIME_CMD='/usr/bin/time -f "%E execution time"'
TIME_CMD ls
```

Second, you can use a function:

```
TIME_CMD() { /usr/bin/time -f "%E execution time" "$@"; }
TIME_CMD ls
```

Third, you can use an array rather than a simple variable:

```
TIME_CMD=(/usr/bin/time -f "%E execution time")
"${TIME_CMD[@]}" ls
```

Note that with an array, you need to expand it with the `"${array[@]}"` idiom to preserve word breaks properly.